# What was wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion

[Is "cultural appropriation" the consumption or just the production of culture by outsiders?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/61830/is-cultural-appropriation-the-consumption-or-just-the-production-of-culture-by)

The unhelpful voting behaviour here is really, really, getting to me. There is nothing unclear, no lack of motivation, nor any issue to do with poor reasoning, on this question.

Neither is it open ended! I am asking something specific.

The users (i.e. poor voters) of this site are driving me to my wits end.

---

1. So I think [I've](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/61891/can-philosophy-ask-questions-about-what-is-moral-or-immoral-without-deriving-the?noredirect=1#comment171492_61891) established that a philosopher *can* ask this question. Because they can ask about ethics independent of allegiance to a philosophical school, and what made it off topic is just that I don't ask for a specific philosophical school's opinion.
2. My issue with that is, I think, that it's not "too broad" a question, as no-one can refer to any literature they know of to answer it.

If it can be answered by philosophy (1) and isn't too broad (2) then what possible reason could it be closed for?

That you can't find the answer is surely not sufficient reason to close a question, however tempting that may be given that the question may generate non-philosophical answers.

---

But forget it, I think I've worked out the issue [here](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/did-you-guys-blow-this-one).

Comment: You need to make clear why you're not asking a question about definitions in contemporary language.

Comment: well, i'm not, and i say why (give reasons to suppose) i'm not? @curiousdannii

Comment: that was implicit, apologies, i'll edit it an explicit mention of why i'm not asking about a non philosophical terminology @curiousdannii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was downvoted again and closed as off-topic! There is no way on earth that it's not a question for philosophers (I asked a philosopher and they answered it as a philosopher: how e.g. they would be looking for reasons why it's unethical and there aren't), rather than it being a question that doesn't have an answer in the encyclopedia.

For shame! Am I even allowed a hint on how it could be made to be on-topic?

Answer (score 0):

You only received one down vote on that question as of this writing.

However, I hope someone can answer your question in an interesting way.

Comment: yeah i NEED to chill out. i mailed someone who appears in the article, and they said, obviously, mere consumption is not really an issue, except in very unusual cases (esoteric religious songs e.g.)